# ionic2 - Cannot resolve all parameters error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm having the following `ts` code.

```
#home.ts
import {Page, NavController} from 'ionic-framework/ionic';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(nav: NavController){
  }
}
```

and I'm getting the following error.

```
Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'HomePage'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'HomePage' is decorated with Injectable.
    at NoAnnotationError.BaseException [as constructor]
```

I've had a look on the [FAQ](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/faq/), [ionic NavController example](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-preview-app/blob/master/app/pages/navigation/basic/pages.ts#L25) and the [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/NavController/). But I cannot spot an error on why its complaining. For me it seems like Im importing  everything correctly.

What I could be doing wrong?

Below are my system info

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.4.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:  
Ionic Version: 2.0.0-beta.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.17
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.8
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.2 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v4.1.1
Xcode version: Xcode 7.0.1 Build version 7A1001
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
constructor(@Inject(NavController) nav:NavController)
```